# Running command in parallel in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have small snippet of code in `pyspark`.

```
# save data frame as temp table 
df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")

# save data frame as csv
df.write.format("csv").save("my_csv")
```

Now the `1st` command executes then only `2nd` will execute.

Is there a way where I can trigger both these commands in `parallel` i.e I want both commands to execute at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use python `multiprocessing`

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def create_temp_view(df):
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")

def write_df(df):
    df.write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").save("my_csv")


p1 = Process(create_temp_view(df))
p1.start()
p2 = Process(write_df(df))
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```